# Reading strings from a file to find unique characters

Tags: python, string, list, file

I'm trying to find words with the most unique letters from a list of strings. The problem for me is not finding the unique words for a string as I know how to do that, no—, my problem is going step-by-step in the list of strings to find each words unique characters.

**Example:** Say that my list of strings is...

**[Apple, Banana, Tiki]**

and what I want the list to look like is

**[Aple, Ban, Tik]**

Whenever I tried to go through step by step, I end up having the entire list smashed together instead of comma separated and all my other solutions have yielded nothing. I can't use any packages or the set() function.

```
def unique_letters(words_list):

    count = 0 
    while(count < len(words_list)):
        for i in lines[count]:
        if i not in temp:
            temp.append(i)
            dupes = ''.join(temp) 
    count += 1
    return dupes
```

What I end up getting is...

```
'ApleBanTik' ### when I want ---> [Aple, Ban, Tik]
```

I've been working on another solution, but I end up getting the same thing. Any suggestions to how I can fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this (with list comprehension):

```
def unique_letters(words_list):
    return [''.join(dict.fromkeys(word)) for word in words_list]
```

Here is the expanded version:

```
def unique_letters(words_list):
    result = []
    for word in words_list:
        result.append(''.join(dict.fromkeys(word)))
    return result
```

When you convert a word into a dictionary, it removes all duplicates. Then, we just convert the dictionary into a string.

Comment: I had a feeling I should have tried dictionaries, this only solves a part of my problem as the other half I omitted from my original question, but now that I have this I'm most certainly sure I can solve the rest. Thank you very much!

Comment: Oops, I got you homie. Just a follow up update, I was able to get the full function working now. Thanks bunches!